# Notepad++ Find and replace using regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to trim a single whitespace in a large txt file using regex within Notepad++'s find and replace function.

The pattern is:

```
06.01.001.01.04
```

Including the space after the 4. All entries follow the same pattern of 2 numbers, dot 2 numbers dot, 3 numbers dot, 2 numbers dot,  2 numbers. There is no dot before or after the numbers.

My understanding is that I can replace the value found with the found value but with the following space removed.

Comment: Why do you need a regex for this? Use the Edit->Blank Operations->Trim Trailing Space menu item.

Comment: Unless it is not at the end. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I did try that but it's not at the end, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find `(\.\d{2})\s`

Replace `$1`

If you have more numbered format, make it more explicit:

Find `(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})\s`

Comment: This is absolutely perfect for my use, thanks so much - you've saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 2):

Following may help you here.

***Place in find following regex:***

```
([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2})\s+
```

***Place following in replace:***

```
$1\n
```

Comment: This solves my problem, but adds a new line instead of removing the extra space. Thanks!

Comment: @ahu77, cool, you could try to remove `\n` from it and it shouldn't add a new line to it then.